# Checking one conditional React prop does not satisfy TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having trouble understanding Typescript. I want to define a `<Component/>` with one required prop `requiredProp`, and a condition prop `extend` which if true, allows to use `extendedProp`.

e.g.

```
<Component requiredProp={''} />   // OK
<Component requiredProp={''} extend={true} requiredProp={Function} />   // OK
<Component requiredProp={''} requiredProp={Function} />   // ERROR
<Component requiredProp={''} extend={true} />   // ERROR
```

My code:

```
// types

interface RequiredProps {
  requiredProp: 'string';
}

type ExtendedProps =
  | {
      extend?: false;
      extendedProp?: never;
    }
  | {
      extend: true;
      extendedProp: Function;
    };

type ComponentProps = RequiredProps & ExtendedProps;


// component

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({requiredProp, extend, extendedProp}) => {
    if (extend) {
        extendedProp(); // ERROR: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
    }
}
```

If I am checking `extend` to be true, shouldn't TS automatically know from `ExtendedProps` that `extendedProp` is also defined?

Compiler is only satisfied if I am explicitly checking `extendedProp` to be defined:

```
    if (extendedProp) {
        extendedProp(); // no error
    }
```

Comment: This is a common issue.  You need to do the check **before** you destructure.  Once you destructure you lose the relationship between properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this using the entire props object, it will work. checking for `props.extend` will narrow down the type on `props`, and thus `props.extendedProp` will be allowed:

```
const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
    if (props.extend) {
        props.extendedProp(); 
    }
}
```

But if you've already split them up into separate variables, then this can't happen. `props` isn't involved in your `if` statement at all, so the type on `props` can't be narrowed. There are just two unrelated local variables, and checking the type on one doesn't do anything to the type on the other.

You and i can recognize that the two variables are related to eachother, but typescript doesn't have the ability to back track to find the origin of the type, and deduce what that means for other types. It may seem simple in this case, but keep in mind that there are a huge variety of lines of code that could be written that would break the linkage, such as:

```
const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({requiredProp, extend, extendedProp}) => {
  extend = Math.random() > 0.5
  if (extend) {
    extendedProp(); 
  }
}
```

Figuring out the implications of those kinds of things is impractical (or maybe impossible);

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3SUSQEcBXYIgEwAUcwAZzgBvcnDhEOXJHwEAuAoJhQaAczLkAvpRgBPMMwCiADzrVus-hCFwAvOLgAfUY4kSkZpBYD8ixgA2gkgU7u6e5pZyNn5w1EgAbvSh7joSLmJhHl4WiirsIW7hOVHWYIoAYuzUGMAQ1CkSWhTk%20oZwAMK4kPG0ZcJ2LNI8-XAAZHCmkVYCgi1o9cqd3fXeMIrI6DAAdBUdADxd4Kt9swB89nAAFGCzAJT2F5nuwJjXtzaC2xHe3A-PWTgHyE3xKMxsVzupDgRTS7iIMHYUGocXYAQCFC0QA)

Comment: Thank you. Probably have read that about destructuring before, but it didn't catch my mind until I got into trouble now.